# Spring Boot - Disable validation logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way I can disable request parameter validation logs from showing up?

They look like the following:

```
2020-07-10 10:04:54.943  WARN 12071 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public [REDACTED]: [Field error in object 'createDemoBootDto' on field 'firstName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.createDemoBootDto.firstName,NotEmpty.firstName,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [createDemoBootDto.firstName,firstName]; arguments []; default message [firstName]]; default message [must not be empty]] ]
```

Given that the application is going to be receiving a lot of requests it does not make sense to log every single validation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior [isn't enabled by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0f264b68e830ef3947120fe1c8847a3d82612ae6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcProperties.java#L99), so please check your application configuration for the following property:

`spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=true`
or
`spring.mvc.logResolvedException=true`

And set it to `false` to disable the logging of resolved exceptions.

**UPDATE**: Depending on what version of Spring (and/or Spring Boot) you're using the `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` may have a mind of its own and [overrides the setting](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L163). There's even [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22159) about it. If my first solution doesn't work, can you try this one:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver=ERROR
```